# How to push admob ads behind navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have added admob ads on the project with navigation drawer. I want the admob ads to be pushed behind the drawer. I have used following xml code but it does not work perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/bannerAdLayout">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy"
   />

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_above="@+id/bannerAdLayout"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please see the attached picture.
[image: Example of problem]

Comment: add this line  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your drawerlayout

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution.
you need to remove Adview from this file and just add that file in
your app_bar_main layout

**UPDATE**
here is my 
*activity_main.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:openDrawer="start">
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is my *app_bar_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/realative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have a example code?

Comment: This does not work correctly. It overlaps the contents of the fragments. I want the adview takes extra space beyond the fragment.

Comment: and provide your app_bar_main .xml file too

Comment: Here is the link of the app_bar_main.xml content... https://pastebin.com/LP7pJn7p

Comment: than why include xml file it self ,,you have to make new xml @Bishwash

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: if this is your app_bar_main file which is you posted than in that file why you use `<include>` of that file it self

Comment: Thats content_main not app_bar_main. Check it again.

Comment: i talk about this `<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: That is the content of activity_main.xml